# Why did my ubuntu machine leave suspend?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hibernate

Sometimes I come upstairs and my computer has left suspend and is booted or booting or whatever.  Is there a log somewhere that will show what caused it to leave suspend? (ie mouse, keyboard, magic packet, power button?)

This is what I see in dmesg:

```
[191069.614821] init: anacron main process (10271) killed by TERM signal
[191072.943409] PM: Marking nosave pages: [mem 0x0009f000-0x000fffff]
[191072.943415] PM: Marking nosave pages: [mem 0xcfdff000-0xffffffff]
[191072.943960] PM: Basic memory bitmaps created
[191072.943961] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[191073.022827] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[191073.024185] PM: Preallocating image memory... done (allocated 605591 pages)
[191076.793570] PM: Allocated 2422364 kbytes in 3.76 seconds (644.24 MB/s)
[191076.793573] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.174 seconds) done.
[191076.968544] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[191076.972184] serial 00:06: disabled
[191076.973326] parport_pc 00:05: disabled
[191077.172545] PM: freeze of devices complete after 203.995 msecs
[191077.172831] PM: late freeze of devices complete after 0.283 msecs
[191077.173250] PM: noirq freeze of devices complete after 0.418 msecs
[191077.173586] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S4
[191077.173904] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[191077.173934] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[191077.276185] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
[191077.277799] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
[191077.278538] Broke affinity for irq 20
[191077.380009] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
[191077.380377] PM: Creating hibernation image:
[191077.384001] PM: Need to copy 397084 pages
[191077.384001] PM: Normal pages needed: 397084 + 1024, available pages: 634408
[191077.384001] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[191077.384001] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[191077.384001] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x1
[191077.384001] Disabled fast string operations
[191077.393728] CPU1 is up
[191077.393765] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x2
[191077.393729] Disabled fast string operations
[191077.407045] CPU2 is up
[191077.407081] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x3
[191077.407047] Disabled fast string operations
[191077.420461] CPU3 is up
[191077.423745] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S4
[191077.456598] PM: noirq restore of devices complete after 15.130 msecs
[191077.456747] PM: early restore of devices complete after 0.105 msecs
```

Linux noosphere-work 3.11.0-12-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 9 16:20:46 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux, ubuntu 13.10

Comment: Its a ghost....

Comment: .... or our cat

Comment: From that log it looks like it never suspended (hibernated actually), it seems to have gone into hibernation and then directly jumped out.